# Runtime error javascript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, error

Lately I get this error (see pic), however if I click continue everything works perfectly and the value is assigned correctly to variable xAppWebUrl. In another script I have similar code that runs without throwing an error. Any ideas what might be wrong here? Thanks!!

Error text in English: "The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it, apparently this does work but thows an error:

```
this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);
ctx.load(this.oListItem);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(
        this,
        function () {
            console.log("scriptAddMenuToListView.js: AppWebUrl successfully retrieved from lstAppData...");
            var xAppWebUrl = this.oListItem.get_item('xValue');
            fxCreateMenuHTML(xAppWebUrl);
        }),
    function () { console.log("scriptAddMenuToListView.js: Query to obtain AppWebUrl from lstAppData failed...") }
    );
```

and this works as well but DOES NOT throw an error:

```
var oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);
ctx.load(oListItem);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        var xAppWebUrl = oListItem.get_item('xValue');
        console.log("scriptAddMenuToListView.js: AppWebUrl successfully retrieved from lstAppData, xAppWebUrl==" + xAppWebUrl);
        fxCreateMenuHTML(xAppWebUrl);
    },
    function () {
        console.log("scriptAddMenuToListView: Query to obtain AppWebUrl from lstAppData failed, msg==" + args.get_message());
    })
```

still don't knw why the first peace of code throws an error though, but happy that things are working now :)

Answer (score 0):

This error typically arises when we try to access a field that was not requested.

Try below

```
ctx.load(this.oListItem, 'Include(xValue)');
```

Comment: the Async query fails when I add the 'Include(xValue)' to ctx.load, Any idea ? Really strange that it throws an error but does assign the value...

Comment: and even weirder that the error is not thrown always, but just sometimes. Maybe has something to do with my monkeyball internet connection.

Comment: Make sure you are executing after SharePoint js files are loaded. Look ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded